# mysql query 2 different data

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table

```
+----+---------------------+----------+
| id | waktu_be5b          | fqi_505  |
+----+---------------------+----------+
| 69 | 2013-10-24 00:31:09 | 334438.1 |
| 70 | 2013-10-24 02:30:20 | 334481.9 |
| 71 | 2013-10-24 05:28:22 | 334524.4 |
| 72 | 2013-10-24 06:19:36 | 334565.5 |
| 73 | 2013-10-24 09:30:34 | 334606.0 |
| 74 | 2013-10-24 10:30:56 | 334648.3 |
| 75 | 2013-10-24 14:11:01 | 334737.9 |
+----+---------------------+----------+
```

how to query 2 data, id 69 and 72 ? iwant to pull data and put on php table, and subraction them

```
<tr >
<th scope="row" class="column1">FQ-505</th>
<td >#</td>
<td ><?php echo $row['fqi_505'];?></td>
    <td ><?php echo $row['fqi_505'];?></td>
<tr>
```

i use dummy table

```
SELECT * FROM `dummy`;
    +---+
    | d |
    +---+
    | 1 |
    +---+
```

and this script;

```
SELECT be5b.id,be5b.waktu_be5b,be5b.fqi_505,dd.id, dd.fqi_505 FROM dummy 
LEFT JOIN  be5b ON ( be5b.waktu_be5b >= '2013-10-24 00:00:00' AND 
be5b.waktu_be5b < '2013-10-24 02:00:00' ) LEFT JOIN be5b as dd ON 
( be5b.waktu_be5b >= '2013-10-24 05:00:00' AND  be5b.waktu_be5b <'2013-10-24 
07:00:00' ) limit 1


+------+---------------------+----------+------+---------+
| id   | waktu_be5b          | fqi_505  | id   | fqi_505 |
+------+---------------------+----------+------+---------+
|   69 | 2013-10-24 00:31:09 | 334438.1 | NULL |    NULL |
+------+---------------------+----------+------+---------+
```

.

Comment: so you know what to do and have a schema too...great....so WHATS THE PROBLEM....???? :)

Comment: The OP has posted his problem: "how to query 2 data, id 69 and 74 ? iwant to pull data and put on php table, and subraction them"

Comment: What should the result set look like?

Comment: @Malky.Kid : i understood that mate, what i meant was that, whats the problem he is facing in achieving his solution! :)

Comment: I try left join, right join, but i can not pull 2 datas that i want

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but assuming that your first **tables name is *`be5b`***, i think your error lies in this condition of your sql
 `( be5b.waktu_be5b >= '2013-10-24 00:00:00' AND be5b.waktu_be5b < '2013-10-24 02:00:00' )`

Your limiting condition is `< 2013-10-24 02:00:00` but the `id : 74` (which you want to pull out) has timestamp `2013-10-24 10:30:56` which is rejected as it is  `> 2013-10-24 02:00:00`....so you don't get the output.
Update this and check if it helps! :)

Comment: I have edited the question,, the id is 69 72,  not 74.. and it's the problem. Assumse, if the script is correct, there is will be the output, not null for this condition

Comment: as in `72`, same goes for `id : 74` too....take a look at its timestamp, its still `> 2013-10-24 02:00:00`! :)

Comment: yes, my limit condition for id 69 is ( be5b.waktu_be5b >= '2013-10-24 00:00:00' AND be5b.waktu_be5b < '2013-10-24 02:00:00' ).. it can be pull out. And for id 75, i limit it with ( be5b.waktu_be5b >= '2013-10-24 05:00:00' AND be5b.waktu_be5b < '2013-10-24 07:00:00' ) at be5b as dd , it produces null. If i change the limit for be5b as dd  ( be5b.waktu_be5b >= '2013-10-24 00:00:00' AND be5b.waktu_be5b < '2013-10-24 07:00:00' ), it goes to first data